# Don't scale image when creating new bitmap from existing image

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how to create a new bitmap from an existing image with a taller height, but don't scale the image and just have transparent, black or white below the original image in the new bitmap?

I basically have one picture that is taller than the second and I need the second one to be as tall as the first, without stretching it.

```
            img2 = new Bitmap(lImages[2],new Size(pictureBox.Image.Width,pictureBox.Image.Height));
            img2 = ((Bitmap)img2).Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox.Image.Width, pictureBox.Image.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

C# .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a `Graphics` object, you can achieve this easily:

```
Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(new Size(pictureBox.Image.Width,pictureBox.Image.Height));
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temp))
{
    g.DrawImage(img2, 0, 0);
}
img2 = temp;
```

Now `img2` references a new `Bitmap` object of the required size which has the original (unstretched) image painted on it.

Note: To control the color of the extra space, add a call to `g.FillRect` before drawing the image.

Answer (score 0):

Create your "standart" size bitmap and fill it with, let's say, white color and call Bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.White) and draw your final image over it.